# How can I get the model name of object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got four different models.

Here's an example,

```
@single = Single.all
@coe = Coe.all
@blend = Blend.all
@production = @single+@coe+@blend
```

then how to check which model @production is?

I tried

```
<% @production.each do |p| %>
  <%=p.class.name%>
<% end %>
```

but it returns "Array"

It seems to be simple, but I can't find out
(I edited question)

Comment: can you share the output of @production and @production.class?

Comment: It returns "Array"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is here

```
@single = Single.all
@coe = Coe.all
@blend = Blend.all
@production = @single+@coe+@blend
```

change these lines with

```
@single = Single.all.to_a
@coe = Coe.all.to_a
@blend = Blend.all.to_a
@production = @single+@coe+@blend
```

and then if you will check

```
@production.first.class.name #Single
@production.last.class.name #Blend
```

so in your view you can do this

```
<% @production.each do |p| %>
  <% p.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.class.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: changed `Object.all` to `Object.all.to_a` worked! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

if while iterating on @production it returns array so you need to try this.

```
<% @production.each do |p| %>
  <% p.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.class.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`@production` is a collections of combinations of single, coe, and blend thats why `@production.class.name` doesnt work, you need to iterate each object like this:

```
<% @production.each do |object| %>
  <%= object.class.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: does objects exists for `@single = Single.all, @coe = Coe.all, @blend = Blend.all` ? if not then results will be NilClass